# The proof for every even degree derivative being divisible by the factorial of the degree

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

So in the process of proving the Maclaurin series for $$\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$
I tried to do prove that for all odd degrees of the derivative, the numerator contains x in every number so when 0 is input into the function, the result is 0, so the summation results in only x's that contain even integer powers. How would I go about proving that for those given derivatives of an even degree, they always contain the factorial of the degree?

eg.
$$f^{6}(x)=(6!)\frac{(7x^6-35x^4+21x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^7}$$

I've tried doing induction as below
By assuming that $$\frac{d^{2k}}{dx^{2k}}(\frac{1}{x^2+1})=(2k)!f(x)$$ and assuming true for n=k+1 by saying $$\frac{d^{2k+2}}{dx^{2k+2}}(\frac{1}{x^2+1})=(2k+2)!g(x)$$ I've tried substituting $$(2k+2)!g(x)=(2k)!(2k+1)(2k+2)g(x)$$ with $$f''(x)$$ and ended with $$g(x)(2k+1)(2k+2)=f''(x)$$ but was not really able to do anything with it. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try induction? For one, you will have to be careful in specifying what "containing the factorial of the degree" actually means, but once you do that, the statement you are left with should be provable by induction.

Comment: I've tried doing induction by assuming that $$\frac{d^{2k}}{dx^{2k}}(\frac{1}{x^2+1})=(2k)!f(x)$$ and assuming true for n=k+1 by saying $$\frac{d^{2k+2}}{dx^{2k+2}}(\frac{1}{x^2+1})=(2k+2)!g(x)$$ but was not able to bring it anywhere from there. I've tried substituting $$(2k+2)!g(x)=(2k)!(2k+1)(2k+2)g(x)$$ with $$f''(x)$$ and ended with $$g(x)(2k+1)(2k+2)=f''(x)$$ but was not really able to do anything with it. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What you wrote in the comment should really be in the body of your question, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it just now.

Comment: Regarding "I tried to do prove that for all odd degrees of the derivative, the numerator contains x in every number so when 0 is input into the function, the result is 0, so the summation results in only x's that contain even integer powers.", you can prove this by pointing out that the function is symmetric about the line $x = 0$. This means that as you keep taking derivatives, it will alternate between being symmetric about $x = 0$ and being ($180^\circ$ rotationally) symmetric about the origin. A function that is symmetric about the origin must go through the origin.

Comment: (There is a reason that the properties $f(-x) = f(x)$ and $f(-x) = -f(x)$ are called even and odd, respectively. Because they imply that the power series contains only even or odd degree terms, respectively.)

Comment: Ahh, cool that is a much simpler proof, thanks. Do you have any idea how I would go as to prove the even derivatives?

Comment: @Isshin If $f(x) = f(-x)$, which is to say, $f$ is an even function, then you may differentiate both sides to get $f'(x) = -f'(-x)$, which is to say $f'$ is an odd function. Inserting $x = 0$ here tells you that $f'(0) = -f'(0)$, and it follows that $f'(0) = 0$. Taking $f'(x) = -f'(-x)$ and differentiating one more time, you get $f''(x) = f''(-x)$, or in other words, $f''$ is an even function. Now you can repeat this from the top, and conclude that $f'''(0) = 0$. And then you can do it again to conclude that the fifth derivative $f'''''(0) = 0$. And so on.

Comment: This does not in any way help you find the even terms of the series. It is only a proof that the odd ones are always $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone trying to see if there is a proof, I've found one and it uses binomial expansion.
$$(x^2+1)^{-1}$$ expanded using the binomial expansion formula gives us terms with $x$ to even powers due to $$x^2$$ being in the term for a.
So when deriving an odd amount of times, there are no constants so when $0$ is input, it results in $0$.
And when deriving an even amount of times, there is only a single constant which is equal to the power being brought down and having $1$ subtracted until it becomes $0$, giving us the factorial of the power or the degree of the derivative.

Comment: What is the meaning of "a" in the phrase "(...) being in the term for a"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the term a in the formula for the binomial expansion $$(a+b)^n$$ so because the term a in this case contains $$x^2$$, every term in the expansion will contain it, after using thr formula and combining exponents, all terms of x will be to an even exponent. I've got a gdoc with a more detailed explanation if you need.